# wordpress theme checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

This is the code I have to display the checkbox in the theme options page:

```
$options[] = array( "name" => "Enable/Disable Slider",
            "desc" => "If you don´t want to see the slider on your homepage you can disable it here.",
            "id" => $shortname."_onoffslider",
            "std" => "",
            "type" => "checkbox",
            "class" => "");
```

The checkbox now is there. And also I have this bit of code to echo the value true or false in my template. like this:

```
        <p>
        <?php if( get_option('_onoffslider') != '') { ?>
        <?php echo get_option('_onoffslider'); ?>

        <?php } else { ?>

        It is ON!

        <?php } ?>
    </p>
```

In the template page the text "It is ON!" always shows, no matter the checkbox is on or off. I know the code is wrong but i can´t fix it.

Any help? thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 <p>
        <?php $shortname="whateveryouhadchosen"; ?>
        <?php if( get_option($shortname.'_onoffslider') != '') { ?>
        <?php echo get_option($shortname.'_onoffslider'); ?>

        <?php } else { ?>

        It is ON!

        <?php } ?>
    </p>
```

Comment: works! but if I put before <?php } else { ?> this text "Is is OFF" it does not work because it will always show "Ii is ON!" What I understand is that it echoes true or false but does not do anything is true or false.

Comment: I solved it with adding this:   <?php if( get_option('of_onoffslider') === 'true') { ?> do this <?php } else { ?>  do that. thanks